# python get rid of default date 1900-01-01

Tags: python, datetime

I am wondering if I can get rid of the 1900-01-01 in my outputs without changing too much of my code. I know there have been one addressing this but I don't understand how I could apply those lines to my code without changing everything. If I could get some giudance I would really appreciate it!

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
time_difference= open('Book1.csv')#it is important that within the csv file that the times do not have extra spaces before, that they are foramtted to military time and that these settings are saved before code is ran
time_difference_csv=csv.reader(time_difference)

for row in time_difference_csv:
    w = [[datetime.strptime(i[0],'%H:%M:%S')]+ [datetime.strptime(i[1],'%H:%M:%S')] for i in time_difference_csv]
for row in w:
   p= (row[1]-row[0])
for row in w:
    l= (row[1]-row[0]) + row[0]

td= open('121Times3.csv')#imports csv with the list of times from one time source; e.g. just the scanner times
td_csv=csv.reader(td)
firstline = True

for row in td_csv:
    if firstline:    #skip first line
        firstline = False
        continue
# parse the line
for row in td_csv:
    k = [[datetime.time.strptime(i[0],'%H:%M:%S')] for i in td_csv]

for row in k:#adds the difference found earlier to all the times on the  csv. Converts all the scanner times to the wall times.
    print row[0] + p
```

Comment: Seeing a portion of your input file will probably help.

Comment: csv 1 input:  Test 1- 12:41:09 Test2-12:43:10            csv input 2: Test 1: 12:45:27